# alternative to global variable for running total

Tags: c#, global-variables, cumulative-sum

I am very much a novice with C#, but for class I must write a program which keeps a running total of food sales.

We have been taught to use global variables, but not only does it not feel like the easiest way, everywhere I read says not to use them.

Without using a global variable, I have not found a way to keep the cost of two different chocolate bars, for example. It works to get the total cost of 1 bar - regardless of quantity, but when I add another, any previous selections disappear from the total cost.

So in short: what I have works, but I feel that I need to learn a better practice.

Here is a sample of my code (note that there is more than one method which I have not copied into here):

```
class Program
{
    static double total = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string choice = "y";

        while (choice == "y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main Menu:\nChocolate\nSandwiches");

            int menu = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (menu)
            {
                case 1:
                    chocolate();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sandwich();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void chocolate()
    {
        int menu = 0;

        //double cost = quant * price;
        Console.WriteLine("Chocolate bar menu:\nMars bar\nSnickers\nTwix\nMilky Bar\nTurkish Delight");

        int chocBar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Quantity");

        double quant = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Clear();

        if (chocBar == 1)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            double costMars = quant * 0.5;
            total = total + costMars;

            Console.WriteLine("current total: £" + total.ToString("0.00"));
            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for main menu");
            menu = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (menu == 1)
            {
                chocolate();
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

        if (chocBar == 2)
        {
            double costSnick = quant * 0.8;
            total = total + costSnick;

            Console.WriteLine("current total: £" + total.ToString("0.00"));
            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for main menu");
            menu = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (menu == 1)
            {
                chocolate();
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations for picking C# as a programming language to learn. It really is a great programming language.

What you read is correct, globals variables have many implications. It is usually last resort. Since you are a beginner I will recommend another simple technique. I found a great link for you that will introduce concepts of passing variables by value and reference. Check it out

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx

Good luck.

Comment: Tough to get my head around but it makes some sense at least. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Good on you for being proactive about learning good coding practices early on in your education!  I think your instructor is probably telling you to use globals for right now so as not to overload you with too many concepts at once, but yeah, as a general rule of thumb, you should try to pass variables around your code as method parameters instead.  The reason is because if you have a global variable in a large application with tens of thousands of lines of code, and that global variable somehow ends up with an incorrect value in it, then it can be a real nightmare to figure out which piece of code wrote the incorrect value into the variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to allow data to flow into and out of methods when calling them. The worst way is to use a "global" variable.

*Aside: C# technically does not have "global" variables per se, as the term describes variables that are fully accessible from any context, without qualification. All C# variables must be scoped to a type or a method. But, the same general caveats do apply to these kinds of variables. In C#, it is the usage that distinguishes whether a variable is declared along best practices or not, not the declaration itself.*

In your code, the most obvious way to approach this would be to have each method return the value to be added to the total.

Also, for some reason, you have implemented your loop as a recursive call. It's not clear to me why you did that, but unless that's a specific requirement in your classroom assignment, I would recommend against it. You're unlikely to run into any specific problems in this context, but it's highly irregular, making the code hard to understand, and giving at least a theoretical possibility of a stack overflow (in reality, you're unlikely to find a user patient enough to cause that to happen, but there's not an actual guarantee in the code that the recursion will eventually terminate).

I am usually hesitant to rewrite homework assignments, but in this case I think you've provided enough code, and advice will be clearer if presented as more code. You still have some work to do, to implement the `sandwich()` method and the other candy bars, and I've only addressed the immediate problem, not the other flaws in the code. So I don't feel like I'm just doing your school-work for you. :)

Here is the general idea of what I think the code *should* look like:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double total = 0;
        string choice = "y";

        while (choice == "y")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main Menu:\nChocolate\nSandwiches");

            int menu = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (menu)
            {
                case 1:
                    total += chocolate();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    total += sandwich();
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("current total: £" + total.ToString("0.00"));
            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 for main menu");
            menu = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    static double chocolate()
    {
        int menu = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Chocolate bar menu:\nMars bar\nSnickers\nTwix\nMilky Bar\nTurkish Delight");

        int chocBar = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Quantity");

        double quant = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Clear();

        double cost;

        switch (chocBar)
        {
        case 1: // Mars
            cost = 0.5;
            break;
        case 2: // Snickers
            cost = 0.8;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Invalid user input");
        }

        Console.Clear();

        return quant * cost;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- It's not clear to me what the point of the prompt for *"Press 1 for main menu"* is. What could the user do at that point *except* return to the main menu? Whatever your intent, it seems likely that you will do the same thing regardless of whether the user has picked the *"Chocolate"* or *"Sandwiches"* option, so I moved that prompt out to the main method.
- When dealing with currency, the `decimal` type is a better choice than `double`, because human beings don't like the rounding error that occurs with base-2 arithmetic in the `double` type. Using the `decimal` type ensures that values entered as decimal remain represented exactly as decimal, eliminating that source of rounding error.
- It's not clear to me whether you really intend for the user to be able to purchase a fraction of a candy bar or not. The type you parse the input as is `double`, which would allow the user to buy e.g. 1.25 candy bars. If that's what you intend, fine. But if not, consider changing the type of the quantity user input to `int`.
- Your original code had no mechanism to break out of the top-level menu, i.e. set `choice` to something other than `"y"`. I did nothing at all to address that. The same issue still exists in the code here.
- *"Turkish Delight"* may describe a wide variety of candies, but I've never seen one that I'd characterize as a chocolate bar. You might want to reconsider the top-level menu item description, if you're going to sell those. :)

Comment: Turkish Delight in England is very much a bar :).

I ran your code and it solves all but one problem; how can I display a running total in each method as I add various items?

Say I add a bar, and that is 80p, then a sandwich which comes to £1.90. I want the total to be displayed constantly - not only when I return to the main menu.

When I try to call the 'total' variable, it says it 'does not exist in the current context'. Once I have that problem solved - we're good to go.

As for returning to the main menu - that has been resolved. The code was far from finished earlier.

Comment: @Matt: unfortunately, the specification is not clear, and the code in your question does little to illuminate. The code in my example always returns to the main loop after entering a single item, so the total is always displayed after each item. But the user has to specify both category and individual item for each item purchased. If you want to add loops in the `chocolate()` and `sandwich()` methods, then you need to pass `total` to each of those methods, use it in there, and then return it from the methods to be assigned back to the `total` local variable in the main loop.

Comment: @Matt: Without a clear, complete specification, it's not possible to know for sure what you need here. Fact is, in such a simple homework-style question, it's not really that bad to just have the `static` field and use it in each method where you want. That's not very different from encapsulating all the logic in an instantiable object, with a non-`static` field where you can keep the running total, and that would be considered reasonably acceptable in a more complex scenario.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm asking. How do I pass the 'total' variable into each of the methods?

I'm learning a lot on here. At the moment, the app works as I would like it to, only I want the running total to always be displayed.

Comment: @Matt: _"How do I pass the 'total' variable into each of the methods?"_ -- sorry, I don't know what you mean. Are you saying that you literally do not know how parameters work? If so, I recommend you read the language documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx. If you need some other kind of help, I'm afraid you need to be more specific.

Comment: I don't know where the confusion is. Just as I am returning the value of each method to the main method - to get the total cost - I wish to show the total cost FROM the main method in each INDIVIDUAL method.

So if I chose a chocolate bar, the cost will be shown whilst inside that menu - not only when I go back to the main menu.

Comment: @Matt: you have a value, in the variable `total`. You want to pass that value to the methods. What _specifically_ are you having trouble understanding, about how to do that? It's one of the most fundamental aspects of programming, to pass values to methods. Did you read the link I provided in my previous comment? Is there _anything_ about passing values to methods that you _do_ understand? The _"confusion"_ is that you aren't being clear about what you need help with. What have you tried? What _specifically_ are you having trouble with?

Comment: I am being quite clear. You are not understanding my question, and yes I did click the link. In fact, I clicked it a while ago when someone else posted it here in reply to my question.

I am asking how to pass the 'total' variable down to each method; chocolate(), sandwich() etc. I cannot be clearer as to what I am asking.

It may be a fundamental aspect, but I only started learning this a few months ago and we have ONE lesson on passing/returning values.